# How to Include Jquery requirement with Firebase Cloud Storage Bucket?

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I've manually uploaded a folder with about 200 files to my Firebase Cloud Storage bucket. The folder is basically an entire game that includes images, media, and a game engine. I'm trying to play the game directly from the bucket using the download url of my index.html.

The problem is that I'm getting an error saying jQuery is not defined.  When I upload the exact same folder the same way to an Amazon s3 bucket, I'm able to play no problem. Am I missing something in my Firebase project (sorry if this seems simple but I'm brand new to Firebase/Google Cloud)? Is there some kind of requirement that I need to include in my Firebase config before my bucket can find jQuery or do I need to add it to a package.json anywhere? The relevant code looks something like this:

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        // Size the canvas to fill the browser viewport.
        jQuery(window).resize(function() {
            sizeCanvas(jQuery(window).width(), jQuery(window).height());
        });


        jQuery(document).ready(function ()
        {           
            // Create new runtime using the canvas
            createRuntime("canvas");
        });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you are you using a Firebase Cloud Storage bucket as a repository for files included in your index.html page (i.e. files like js, css or images).

Why don't you upload them the same way you upload the index.html, I mean using the Hosting service of Firebase, which is exactly dedicated to this kind of requirements? I.e.: "deploy web apps and static content to a global content-delivery network (CDN)" (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/)

Comment: One more point: from the index.html page you cannot point to a file stored in a Storage bucket simply like: <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> The url of the object in the bucket would be something like https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxx.appspot.com/o/jquery-2.1.1.min.js....

Comment: Thanks for your response. That has been part of my issue for these last hours - the fact that there isn't a readily available public url. Part of my requirements is that I'm building something that need to know the asset locations ahead of time. That's because I'm hosting pre-written games with references to images/audio/etc. So I needed public urls. 

I finally found a solution though. Since Firebase Cloud uses Google Cloud Storage under the hood, I was able to get a public url for my assets out of there. Thanks again

Comment: Ok, note however that it might be probably more efficient to host your files through Firebase Hosting

Comment: Thanks for following up - . Was actually doing more research on Hosting vs. Storage. Hosting may indeed be a better use for me, but I'm not sure. I'm basically building a platform where my admins can change certain image assets on many on different games. The players of the game need to see the correct images per admin. So I need to make sure I have a reference to the game assets an admin needs to change. That's why I was thinking having a public url would make it easier to do so; however, I'm wondering if things can be accomplished using hosting and cloudstore/database